# upload restful Web Service for Mobile Apps to cpanel

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I'm trying to upload created restful webservice to be consumed by mobile apps. I started using netbeans IDE 8 to create it but when I got to publishing it on the cpanel, I created a .war file and uploaded it through cpanel. my cpanel server support java and index.jsp file is accessible but I can't seem to access my webservice.
how can i access to my webservice on this cpanel?